# What's the most efficient way to save data in MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

Hi I have data that I need to store in my database. My website is about tv-shows, and the data I'm talking about is basically *seasons* and *episodes*. My concern is about whether I should use two tables or one. I'll make myself more clear:

**Option 1:**

*seasons_table*

- post_id
- season_number
- season_title
- language
- subtitles
- item_date (when it was created)
- item_modified (when it was last modified)

*episodes_table*

- post_id
- season_id
- episode_number
- episode_title
- item_date
- item_modified

**Option 2:**

*unique table*

- post_id
- item_type (season or episode)
- season_number
- season_title
- language
- subtitles
- season_id
- episode_number
- episode_title
- item_date
- item_modified

I can already see for myself that with **Option 1** there's gonna be a lot of common fields between the two tables, while with **Option 2** there's gonna be a lot of fields that are never gonna be used (e.g. an episode will never have a value in the field season_title since it just needs a value for season_id to be linked to that season).

So which one is the best option? I'm willing to choose option 2, but I'm worried that those empty fields are gonna waste memory or loading time or whatever while processing any data in that table. Is that true? Thanks in advance to everyone, I hope I made myself clear.

By the way my website is wordpress based and I'm gonna use a custom table, but I think i'm gonna use some wordpress functions to process data like `$wpdb->insert` and so on...

Comment: The best option is to apply the principles of normalization

Comment: Read more about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization and have in mind of future plans, example if you want reviews, forum posts, etc. You see my point... Option 1 is more safe. I would maybe put out the subtitle, as there might be difference in subtitles available for one season to another. I would put that on an episode relation (a new table for subtitle episode relation)

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. @MrSimpleMind: the point is, if I have one season with episodes both with and without subtitles, it's gonna be shown as two seasons: e.g. Season 3 (eng) and Season 3 (sub eng) with the same amount of episodes but maybe with different names and surely with different links. Yeah I thought about future plans and that's also a concern, but I can always add a column to the unique table in Option 2, right?

Comment: I understand how you think, even if I wouldnt do like that :) .. Of course you can add new columns later. But I would actually have one season no matter what subtitle is. And then have  a relation table for subtitle etc. This way I can have nice statistics too, how many were interested in season X... instead of how many where interested in Season X and Y and Z (as those are same season but diff subtitles)... well, both works. Just have in mind also the statistics and analytics behind the model :)

Comment: Thank you for this further explanation, now I understood what you meant and I agree with you, there is no need to have 2 items in the db for the same season, regardless that it will be shown as one or as two... thanks a lot :) I'm gonna choose Option 1 then, since the reasons behind option 2 were just lazyness and the hope that empty fields wouldn't cause a waste of time or memory

Comment: You are welcome, and good luck with your project. Also check google for `joins visualized` .. for example http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ ... will help you alot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two tables is the best approach here, that more closely adheres to the rules of [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). If there's concern about duplication you need to better evaluate where you're storing data.

`item_date` and `item_modified` are probably unique for each entry even if they are "duplicated" in terms of schema. Don't worry about this.

Whatever `post_id` is, you'll have to evaluate if you have a direct relationship between post and these two tables, or from post to seasons to episodes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `post_id` is simply the ID of the post the season/episode belongs to, so it's necessary for the seasons and optional for the episode, but I want it on the episode so I can, for example, count how many episodes belongs to a tv-show without the need to cycle all the seasons. `item_date` and `item_modified` are not an issue, their values will be different only if I'll edit the item some time after creation. I didn't understand the part "where you're storing data" what did you mean? Anyway thanks again for your answer, the database normalization is what I was looking for

Comment: Each entity should have all of its properties stored within its own table. For example it would be a mistake to duplicate the season name in the episode table, or to have episode fields in the season table. Does "post" refer to a show? If so having that direct relationship to both might make sense, but using the seasons table for a quick `JOIN` is usually not hard.

Comment: Alright thank you again, maybe then I need to learn more about database processing data at all (never heard of JOIN) instead of looking for a shortcut while creating the table :) Thanks again

Comment: Using `JOIN` can be [a little dizzying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) but it's one of the most powerful tools in a relational database. I think you're asking all the right questions here, so keep at it and this will all seem routine in time.

Comment: This is more of an organizational problem than a performance one, but with the right table indexes performance will not be an issue, even for GB of data. Don't forget to index on anything that frequently shows up in a `WHERE` clause or `ORDER BY`.

Comment: This is what I wanted to know, thanks a lot! If performance won't be affected that much, then I'm gonna go with Option 1 and handle two tables also with the help of JOIN. Thanks!